# UWP Binding to ComboBoxItem using resources and converter

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I have such ComboBox:

```
<ComboBox Grid.Column="1" Padding="0" Margin="5,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" IsEnabled="{Binding CanUserEdit}" SelectedValue="{Binding ConfigValue, Converter={StaticResource BoolToStringConverter}, Mode=TwoWay}">
      <ComboBoxItem x:Uid="NoButton" />
      <ComboBoxItem x:Uid="YesButton" />
</ComboBox>
```

It's supposed to be normal Yes/No kind of ComboBox, but I wanted to avoid binding to some Yes/No ItemsSource to avoid unnecessary complications.

BoolToStringConverter looks like that:

```
public class BoolToStringConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        var val = value as bool?;

        if (val == true)
            return ResourceLoader.GetForCurrentView().GetString("YesButton/Content");
        else
            return ResourceLoader.GetForCurrentView().GetString("NoButton/Content");
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        var val = value as string;

        if (val == ResourceLoader.GetForCurrentView().GetString("YesButton/Content"))
            return new bool?(true);
        else
            return new bool?(false);
    }
}
```

So generally speaking I have string from resources inside ComboBoxItem while value inside ViewModel is an object (it's not bool, it's not so simple as I'm using TemplateSelector, ComboBox is supposed to be used only for boolean values, others would be normal TextBox with string inside).

I take the value from ViewModel convert it to exact same string from resources but it's not mapping the SelectedValue when control is loaded (ComboBox is empty even though it contains Yes/No values as it should). But "ConvertBack" works normally. When I select something in this ComboBox (for example "No" value) it will properly go inside ConvertBack method, compare the string and set the correct bool? value inside ViewModel. Therefore ConvertBack works well, but initial Convert doesn't set the SelectedValue properly because it's seems to not recognize "Yes" as "Yes" and "No" as "No" at this point (probably because it tries to compare references between string and ComboBoxItem). How can I resolve that?

It works when I use x:String instead of ComboBoxItem ...but x:String cannot be localized and I don't want to make it hardcoded for certain language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the type mismatch.

In your XAML, the child item type of the `ComboBox` is **ComboBoxItem**, and your `BoolToStringConverter.Convert` method returns a **string**. These two types cannot establish the correct equivalent relationship.

You can try setting the `SelectedValuePath` property in the `ComboBox`:

```xml
<ComboBox Grid.Column="1" 
          ...
          SelectedValuePath="Content">
    <ComboBoxItem x:Uid="NoButton" />
    <ComboBoxItem x:Uid="YesButton" />
</ComboBox>
```

But I recommend using `ItemsSource` for data source binding and using `DataTemplate` to set the layout of children.

Here is an example about **binding**, you can do the same on `ComboBox`

Best regards.

Comment: I will go with SelectedValuePath (why I even forgot about it?). This is better way in this example because it will encapsulate whole display and selection logic inside View. With ItemsSource I would need to check the type inside ViewModel to create diffrent bindings exclusively for boolean values (I have this right now and it looks really bad and complicated). Right now I don't need to think about anything - I just set the ConfigValue without even thinking about the type and TemplateSelector will figure out to use ComboBox that will have it's two language-dependent yes/no values.

Comment: Hi, I'm glad to help you solve the problem. I understand your choice, data model binding is to facilitate data reuse, you can decide whether to use it according to your needs